# Redirecting mobile/desktop users through javascript/php

Tags: javascript, php, redirect, mobile, desktop

Hey I've been trying to look for a script that does this but haven't had any luck. I am sending traffic to subdomain.domain.com and want to redirect desktop traffic to subdomain.domain.com/desktop/ and mobile traffic to subdomain.domain.com/mobile/

Is there an easy way to do this, I've only found scripts that redirect users away from your desktop site.

Comment: Well if you find a solution that identfies mobile user (see [Adimz answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25466118/413531)), you automatically know that the ones _not_ identified are desktop users (assuming you just care about those two types). So all you need to do is redirect the non-mobile users to /desktop/

Answer (score 2):

[Detectmobilebrowsers.com](http://detectmobilebrowsers.com/)

I'm sure it will help you in any language you would like to use :-)